# Apache on Cent OS 7 Serving all php files except one

Tags: php, sql, apache, centos

PHP is being commented out CLIENT SIDE (I am guessing) on one of my php files inside the html directory on the Cent OS apache (httpd) in this manner:

```
<!--?php echo 'php says hello (:'; ?-->
```

Full page (source):

```
<html>
  <body>
  Hello!<br>
  <?php echo 'php says hello (:'; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

This EXACT file under a different name will have the php compiled by the server without issue.

Did a full reboot of the system, same problem.

PHP Version: 5.6.19
Apache Version: 2.4.6

This page was not ORIGINALLY the above 6 line source as above. It was the page for displaying categories (which another group member worked on) and my guess is that when it was first requested there was a prevented crash and that file is now cached by Apache, not allowing it to be served.

To be more specific, we were following THIS tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-phpmysql-powered-forum-from-scratch--net-10188

and the category.php file is the one in question.

The way they interface with SQL had to be changed to use sqli and the latest version of php also does not support the particular input sanitation function they were using so all of that was changed.

Before changes were made the category.php file had syntax errors and when it was first loaded by someone, php code was being displayed in the body.

tl;dr requested page with old/different sql/php functions and now the specific file is not being served by Apache (only one filename)

Comment: Check owner of file and it's permission. Are they correct?

Comment: Have tested both as root user and as the generic user set up for others. The html directory is set up so the generic user owns the files (I am not sure what is best practice). I have experimented with different version of the file and when the mysql_real_escape_string function is used, the filename is no longer served by Apache from that point forward even if it is changed (have tested with two files names now).